# IIS ASP.NET Core OpenIddict certificates access

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iis, openiddict

I using OpenIddict with ASP.NET Core like this:

```
X509KeyStorageFlags storageFkags = X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet;

using FileStream fse = File.Open(Path.Combine(environment.ContentRootPath, openIddictConfig.EncryptionCertificate.FilePath), FileMode.Open);
options.AddEncryptionCertificate(fse, openIddictConfig.EncryptionCertificate.Password, storageFkags);

using FileStream fss = File.Open(Path.Combine(environment.ContentRootPath, openIddictConfig.SigningCertificate.FilePath), FileMode.Open);
options.AddSigningCertificate(fss, openIddictConfig.SigningCertificate.Password, storageFkags);
```

But when I'm publishing app to IIS, I get error

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException
>
> Application '/LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT' with physical root 'C:\MySite' hit unexpected managed exception, exception code = '0xe0434352'. First 30KB characters of captured stdout and stderr logs:
> Unhandled exception. System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\MySite\Certificates\Production.EncryptionCertificate.pfx' is denied.
>
> at Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle.CreateFile(String fullPath, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, FileOptions options)
> at Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle.Open(String fullPath, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, FileOptions options, Int64 preallocationSize, Nullable`1 unixCreateMode)   at System.IO.Strategies.OSFileStreamStrategy..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, FileOptions options, Int64 preallocationSize, Nullable`1 unixCreateMode)
> at System.IO.Strategies.FileStreamHelpers.ChooseStrategyCore(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, FileOptions options, Int64 preallocationSize, Nullable`1 unixCreateMode)
> at System.IO.File.Open(String path, FileMode mode)
> at MySite.Infrastructure.DependencyInjection.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.b__4(OpenIddictServerBuilder options)

It can be solved by changing ApplicationPool to `Administartor` instead of `ApplicationPoolIdentity` (first on screen):

[image]

But I guess its bad practice. How can I solve this issue while using `ApplicationPoolIdentity`?

Answer (score 0):

It might be a permissions issue. When you use ApplicationPoolIdentity as the identity of the application pool, insufficient permissions cause access to the certificate to be denied.

You can try the following: Your certificate folder path: C:\MySite\Certificates, right click on the folder and select "Properties" > select the "Security" tab > click the "Edit" button > click the "Add" button > type **IIS AppPool\YourAppPoolName** ( For example: IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool) > click "Check Names" > click "OK" and close the dialog box > select the account you just added and check whether it has corresponding permissions > click "OK".

[image]